# Need to identify a diode

Tags: hardware

I need help as i'm new to reverse engineering. I need to identify a diode in a PCB that i'm currently working on. Do you guys have any idea or advise on how to identify the diode. The diode which I need to identify is D1 on the picture below.

[image: the diode which i want to identify is D1]

Comment: If you have multimeter you can desolder diode from PCB and use diode tester and measure it.

Comment: I tried to desolder it and try to measure it but i didn't get anything

Answer (score 1):

Electronics are not really our focus and it's not clear at all what you plan to do with the information but a quick search found [this blog post](https://ourpastimes.com/identify-diode-markings-7679008.html) which says:

> ### Signal Diodes
>
> The smallest discrete diodes are designed to handle
> about 100 milliamps of current. These devices are typically packaged
> in tiny **glass cylinders** with a connecting lead at each end. A **stripe**
> on the cylinder marks the diode’s cathode, making the opposite side
> the anode. With some diodes, you may need a magnifying glass to see
> the stripe clearly.

(emphasis mine)

IF you need more help with the circuit, I'd suggest asking on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ where there are many more experts on this topic.